# Expand Highslide image using separate text anchor

Tags: highslide

I am successfully using Highslide to expand an image when the thumbnail is clicked. I'm having trouble getting the image to expand when the anchor in the `<p>` tags below it is clicked.

```
<div class="highslide-gallery">
    ...
    <div class="feature">
        <a href="/images/001.jpg" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1)">
            <img src="/images/thumbs/001.jpg" />
        </a>
        <p>
            <a href="/images/001.jpg" onclick="hs.expand(null, {src: '/images/001.jpg'});">Anchor Text</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

When the page loads, two instances of the expanded image are displayed, one on top of the other.

Clicking on each image closes the image as normal.

Clicking on the image thumbnail causes two expanded images to appear.

Clicking on the anchor text works correctly, i.e. one image is expanded and it closes normally when clicked.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image expands twice on page load because you are using `null` instead of `this` in the onclick for the anchor text.

Correct onclick:

```
<a href="/images/001.jpg" onclick="return hs.expand(this)">Anchor Text</a>
```

Comment: Thanks so much - this works perfectly. I had gotten confused with what `this` was referring to.

Comment: Just don't try to combine that with a thumbstrip. The thumbstrip will pick up both the thumbnail image and the text anchor, and will show them as two thumbnails in the strip!

Comment: See this FAQ: [How do I remove the gallery controls from my HTML popup?](http://www.highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=5093) (applies to the thumbstrip too). We also have a special code for this - see this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/roadrash/KAMNp/

Answer (score 0):

Just put the links together:

```
div class="highslide-gallery">
    ...
    <div class="feature">
        <a href="/images/001.jpg" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1)">
            <img src="/images/thumbs/001.jpg" /><p>Anchor Text</p>
        </a>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: This changes the layout of my page, so unfortunately it won't work as a solution. The answer by @RoadRash is exactly what I was after.